# Qt qsqlite db file update / remove

Tags: database, qt, file

In my program I use qsqlite database. I changed the data in the database and then I iterated through the updated database but It took no effect, I could see only the old data. Nothing helped me until I manually deleted the db file so the new one was created, containing the desired new data.

I didn't use any exec to put my new data in the database. I just rewrote it manually with new values.

I wonder what I have to do in order to see my new data without manually deleting the db file. Can I update the binary db file? Or could I remove it after the connection is closed from within the program?

I consider this as a basic question still I can't find the answer.

Comment: did you try to close the database, set the new path and open it again?

Comment: I closed the database but didn't change the path of it. I'd like the database file to be placed at one destination. If the path is changed a new db file is created (with corrected values).

Comment: Add example code demonstrating the problem